# how to set an attribute to a selected item of a dropdown list in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to add an attribute `selected="selected"` to the selected item in a dropdown list in jQuery. If I change to an other item I like to set selected to that new one etc.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#to").change(function() {
    $("#to option").val('Saab').attr("selected", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  Name: <input type="text" name="user"><br> Car:
  <select id="to">
    <option>Volvo</option>
    <option >Saab</option>
    <option>Mercedes</option>
    <option>Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

[Here' a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akrima/1eeomaom/) with the the code

Comment: Why do you need do that, if the item is already selected?

Comment: Firstly, please place all relevant code in the question. People shouldn't have to go off site to understand your question. Secondly, it's not clear what you're attempting to do. After the user selects an item you want to force the selection of a completely different item? You're also using the setter of `val()` so it will never work. If you want to set a value when the page loads use the setter of `val()` without the `change` event handler, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1eeomaom/1/

Comment: if for example i selected x i would like to set the selected to it and if i change to y do the same etc

Comment: Sorry, again that makes no sense. You don't need JS to do that - it's how the HTML control works by default.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: if i select Saab i wand to set selected="selected " do the same if i change to Audi and to Mercedess etc

Comment: ... I have no idea what you're trying to do - or why the standard control doesn't work for you.

Comment: i mean set attribute selected="selected" to the selected item in the dropdownlist

Comment: Then use `attr()` on the `:selected` option: https://jsfiddle.net/1eeomaom/2/. I really don't see what you'd need to do this, though.

Comment: Glad we got there in the end :) I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment under the question:

> I mean set attribute selected="selected" to the selected item in the dropdownlist

To achieve this you can use `:selected` to retrieve the chosen `option` element before using `attr()` to set the attribute on the element. You will also need to use `removeAttr()` on the other `option` elements that were previously selected, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#to").change(function() {
    $('#to option').removeAttr('selected').filter(':selected').attr("selected", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form action="">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="user">
  <br> Car:
  <select id="to">
    <option>Volvo</option>
    <option>Saab</option>
    <option>Mercedes</option>
    <option>Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
```